# How can I write the statement "the product of two negative integers is positive" using quantifiers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How can I write the statement"the product of two negative integers is positive" using quantifiers?

Comment: $$\forall x,y \in \Bbb{Z} , ((x < 0) \wedge (y < 0)) \Rightarrow xy >0$$

Comment: @Crostul integers. And you misplaced a bracket.

Comment: @drhab "$\ldots\in\mathbb Z$".

Comment: @Did Nice feeling to be put on the same line as Crostul.

Answer (score 1):

$\forall x \forall y ((x<0) \land (y<0) \implies (x \times y > 0))$